# JavaScript Toggle Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

Can anyone explain why the snippet of code below does not actually cause the "#wrapper" to shift? It's driving me insane...Nothing happens when I click on the info icon.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary"> 
        <div class="panel-heading">{{item.entree}}</div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x info myButton"></i>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{item.primary_image}}" alt="{{item.entree}}">
            <p class="menu_desc price-widget">{{item.description}}</p>
        </div>    
        <div class="panel-body">{{item.side}}</div>
        <div class="center" style="width: 85%; margin-bottom: 7px;">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-4">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn qtyminus" data-name="quantity" data-value="2" data-id="50" field='{{item.meal_type}}'>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <input class="form-control cart-qty" id="{{item.meal_type}}" type="text" name="{{item.meal_type}}" min="0" max="21" value="{{sub.pork}}">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn qtyplus" data-name="quantity" data-value="2" data-id="50" field='{{item.meal_type}}'>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<script>
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';
    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: "right" };
    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;
    $('#wrapper').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
</script>
```

Comment: is jQuery UI included in page? That signature of `toggle()` is not part of jQuery core it is an overload method requiring jQueryUI. Any errors thrown?

Comment: jQuery UI is included as 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 and <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: so is that code block really after the html in page? If not is it wrapped in a `document.ready` handler? A demo reproducing this would help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a class in button

```
<button class="myButton">
```

```js
$(".myButton").click(function() {
   console.log("123")
   // Set the effect type
   var effect = 'slide';
   // Set the options for the effect type chosen
   var options = {
    direction: "right"
   };
   // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
   var duration = 500;
   $('#wrapper').toggle(effect, options, duration);
  $('#wrapper').hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">{{item.entree}}</div>
   <div id="wrapper">
              hide
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x info myButton"></i>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{item.primary_image}}" alt="{{item.entree}}">
    <p class="menu_desc price-widget">{{item.description}}</p>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">{{item.side}}</div>
   <div class="center" style="width: 85%; margin-bottom: 7px;">
    <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-4">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn qtyminus" data-name="quantity" data-value="2" data-id="50" field='{{item.meal_type}}'>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
     </span>
     <input class="form-control cart-qty" id="{{item.meal_type}}" type="text" name="{{item.meal_type}}" min="0" max="21" value="{{sub.pork}}">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="myButton" type="button" class="btn qtyplus" data-name="quantity" data-value="2" data-id="50" field='{{item.meal_type}}'>
                            test<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

You can see the front end of knowledge:https://github.com/AutumnsWind

Comment: You can see above, I have <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x info myButton"></i>. It doesn't have anything to do with using an actual button.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the snippet below.

I included jQuery and jQueryUI, resized the i-tag and included the text "Image", so you can click on it. Seems to be working!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary"> 
        <div class="panel-heading">{{item.entree}}</div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x info myButton" style="width:20px; height:20px">Image</i>
            <img class="img-responsive myButton" src="/media/{{item.primary_image}}" alt="{{item.entree}}">
            <p class="menu_desc price-widget">{{item.description}}</p>
        </div>    
        <div class="panel-body">{{item.side}}</div>
        <div class="center" style="width: 85%; margin-bottom: 7px;">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-4">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn qtyminus" data-name="quantity" data-value="2" data-id="50" field='{{item.meal_type}}'>
                                <i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <input class="form-control cart-qty" id="{{item.meal_type}}" type="text" name="{{item.meal_type}}" min="0" max="21" value="{{sub.pork}}">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn qtyplus" data-name="quantity" data-value="2" data-id="50" field='{{item.meal_type}}'>
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<script>
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';
    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: "right" };
    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;
    $('.center').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I run the code snippet on SO, it works. When I use it in my site -- exactly as you have it -- it does not work...

Comment: Are you sure jQueryUI is included _after_ jQuery? Perhaps the wrong toggle is called (jQuery toggle instead of jQueryUI toggle), without any errors being thrown.

Comment: I included the src's in the head of the page. Is that the correct place to put them?

Comment: Should work. Have you checked the console for any error messages?